# Run-Time Error 1004: Text To Columns Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba, macos, export, runtime-error

I have been working on this since yesterday. I am trying to create a macro, I have tried numerous methods, however  I keep getting the error message 'Run-time error '1004': TextToColumns method of Range class failed'. Do you know what is

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```
tbl = req_get(url1, ck, authenticate)
    c.SetText tbl
    c.PutInClipboard

With ws
 If r = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 0 Then
        r = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Else:
        r = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        .Activate
        .Cells(r, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayasIcon:=False, noHTMLFormatting:=True
        If .Cells(1, 2) = "" Then .Columns(1).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, consecutivedelimiter:=False, Comma:=True

Sheets("Rooster").Range("P1") = "Shift Patty"
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q1") = "Shift"
endrow = Sheets("Rooster").Cells(1048576, 20).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For g = endrow To Sheets("Rooster").Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = Left(Sheets("Rooster").Range("M" & g), 2)
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "DB" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "BHD"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "NA" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "FHN"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "DC" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "Donut"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "DA" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "FHD"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "X1" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "FLEX"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "AC" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "FLEX"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "RT" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "BHN"
End If
If Sheets("Rooster").Range("P" & g) = "PT" Then
Sheets("Rooster").Range("Q" & g) = "PT"
End If

Next g


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any data in column 1?

Comment: Also note that `.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 0` will always be `False`. Also that line should be `If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then`.

Comment: no there isnt any data on column one however it states it does. I even restarted the macro from fresh start

Comment: If there's no data pasted in column 1, then text-to-columns will fail.

Comment: After correcting that line it gave me another bug to debug pastespecial method of worksheet class failed run-time error 1004 (>.<\)

Comment: You didn't copy anything?

Comment: No I did not copy anything